# batch api call to DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have project with Django-rest-framework, in frontend there is issue for get multiple API routes in one request. I dont want make project complex and dirty for this request, I want create some wrapper to solve this issue

for example:

post with data:

```
[{'method': 'get', 'url': '/api/v1/get_profile'},
{'method': 'get', 'url', '/api/v1/setting'},
{'method': 'get', 'url', '/api/v1/news'}]
```

and receive something like

```
[{'url': '/api/v1/get_profile', data:{'username':'test'}},
{'url': '/api/v1/setting', data:{'can_see_x': 'true'}},
{'url': '/api/v1/news', data:[{'title':'news1'}]}]
```

is there any open source plugin for this?

if no, how can call each api from one view? is it safe? ( all request must be for current user and current token)

where is best spot for this module? create new module named batch for example?

Comment: your question is unclear, may be thats why no response yet!!! Can you tell the co-relation between `url`, `method` and `data`?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do this, you need to make a GET request to your APIs, but sending the URLs and HTTP verbs and API will do the client work, is not the clean way to consume an API

Comment: @NoobEditor client say which url and with with method and args, and server generate response for each url and client use it all

Comment: @EmadMokhtar I know this is bad and anti pattern for decoupling, but for heavy load server, reduce request count can be very important